# Why is this React component state recognized in the JSX return() for the first <p> but not for the second <p>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this component JSX return() shown at the bottom, the `summaryData[0].ceo` is recognized and rendered in:

```
{isDescriptionShown && (
   <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
)}
```

but is undefined in the next paragraph:

```
<p>
  <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
</p>
```

I've also tried:

```
<p>
  <strong>CEO: </strong> <span>{summaryData[0].ceo}</span>
</p>
```

The error thrown is seen here:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  57 |          <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
  58 |      )}
  59 |      <p>
> 60 |          <strong>CEO: </strong> <span>{summaryData[0].ceo}</span>
     | ^  61 |      </p>
  62 |  </div>
  63 | </div>
```

and the order of the two paragraphs does not make a difference. The error is always thrown on

```
    <p>
        <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
    </p>
```

no matter if it comes first or second. I'd like to understand the root cause of this if possible.

Full component code:

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CompanySymbolContext } from "../../../../utils/companyContext";
import { faInfoCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import _ from "lodash";
import "./company-header.styles.scss";

function CompanyHeader() {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const { companySymbol, setCompanySymbol } = useContext(CompanySymbolContext);
    const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState();
    const [isDescriptionShown, setIsDescriptionShown] = useState(false);

    const summaryUrl = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/${companySymbol}?apikey=removedForPublicPost`;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!summaryUrl) return;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            console.log("fetching summary data");
            const response = await fetch(summaryUrl);
            const data = await response.json();
            setSummaryData(data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [summaryUrl]);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter" && inputRef.current.value) {
            const uppercaseCompanySymbol = _.upperCase(inputRef.current.value);
            setCompanySymbol(uppercaseCompanySymbol);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className="company-header">
            {console.log(summaryData)}
            <div className="company-search-container">
                <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                <input
                    className="company-input-box"
                    ref={inputRef}
                    onKeyPress={handleSubmit}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="company-details">
                <h2>
                    {companySymbol}
                    <span className="description-icon">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                            onMouseEnter={() => setIsDescriptionShown(true)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setIsDescriptionShown(false)}
                            className="fa-info-circle"
                            icon={faInfoCircle}
                        ></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    </span>
                </h2>
                {isDescriptionShown && (
                    <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
                )}
                <p>
                    <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CompanyHeader;
```

Comment: Well, I figured it out right as two other people came in and figured it out. Hope it works for you now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your state starts as `undefined`, because no initial value is provided as an argument to `useState`:

```js
const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState();
```

Then later you set that state from an async effect:

```js
setSummaryData(data);
```

But before that completes, your component must render.

Then we get to this line:

```
{isDescriptionShown && (
  <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
)}
```

`summaryData` is undefined but `isDescriptionShown` is only true when the info icon has been `mouseover`'d, so this `<p>` doesn't render

Then we get to this line:

```
<p>
  <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
</p>
```

And `summaryData` is still undefined (the async fetch has not yet been completed). And so you get the crash.

---

The variable is undefined in both cases. But the code that drilling into that variable is only executed in one of those snippets.

To fix it you have to gracefully handle the case where the state is undefined because nothing has been loaded yet.

Something like:

```
{summaryData && isDescriptionShown && (
  <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
)}
{summaryData && <p>
  <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
</p>}
```

Comment: Good answer, only one difference. It has less to do with the async function itself, and more to do with the fact that `useEffect` does not run until after the first render.

Comment: True, this would happen with _any_ `useEffect` that sets that state. Good point!

Answer (score 0):

It is hitting this error because when it is first rendered, `summaryData` is set to null.

`useEffect`, although written before the return, is not run until after the elements in the document start rendering. This causes an error upon first render.

---

`const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState();`   This sets summary data to Null.

Upon the first render, in this line:

```
{isDescriptionShown && (
                    <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
                )}
                <p>
                    <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
                </p>
```

`isDescription` is false upon the first Render, so it does not come across the instance of `summaryData` in this line, and will not until useEffect has already rendered a company.

---

A fairly simple fix (but maybe not the best way to go about it) would be to first check for summaryData before rendering it.

Something like:

`<strong>CEO: </strong> { summaryData ? {summaryData[0].ceo} : ''}`

or

`<strong>CEO: </strong> { summaryData && ({summaryData[0].ceo})}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `summaryData` has the value `undefined` until you set it inside of your `useEffect`, so on the first render, there's an error since `undefined` has no property `0`.

By the time you're setting `isDescriptionShown` to true, `summaryData` has already been set in the `useEffect`, so you don't notice the problem.

You need to make sure that `summaryData` is defined before trying to access properties on it.

```
{!!summaryData && <>
  {isDescriptionShown && (
    <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
  )}
  <p>
    <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
  </p>
</>}
```

Alernatively, you can do this:

```
{!!summaryData && isDescriptionShown && (
  <p className="company-description">{summaryData[0].ceo}</p>
)}

{!!summaryData && <p>
  <strong>CEO: </strong> {summaryData[0].ceo}
</p>}
```